# String with subscript in R

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, subscript

I would like to have an (capital) `H` subscripted in a string (as the name of a column of a dataframe, the goal is not a subricpt printed in a plot). I know I can save a symbol with its unicode character, as for example `x <- c("\u03c9")` for an omega. But how to add an `H` subscripted?

Thank you!

Comment: It's important to know the context here. E.g., this would be very simple if you intend to use this in a plot. If you want to use it in a markdown document, you'd need a different approach.

Comment: It is not for using in a plot, just for using as a column name in a dataframe and to print some results not necessary in a rmarkdown but in a simple text file (in Linux)

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't work on a Windows system (because UTF-8 is not the native encoding there):

```
data.frame("h\u2095" = 1)
#  hₕ
#1  1
```

You usually can find such unicodes by searching google with a search term like "subscript h unicode".

Comment: I searched in google but I have not found a subscript of a capital H unicode.

Comment: For me this is the first hit: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2095

Comment: That is a small `h`, not a capital `H`.

Comment: Well, there appears to be no subscript capital H unicode character. That means you can't have a subscript capital H in data.frame column names. You'll have to use an alternative solution to your approach.